# Warning: Missing argument 2 for image_hwstring()

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

> **Warning: Missing argument 2 for image_hwstring()**,
>
> called in ...\wp-content\plugins\image-widget\image-widget.php *on
>   line 304*
>
> and defined in ...\wp-includes\media.php *on line 103*

This error just appeared for the first time after I switched from using MAMP on iMac for my local dev environment to using WAMP in Windows.

As you can see the error originates from a plugin/from a Wordpress core file...

I can stop the error from appearing by putting `@ini_set('display_errors', 0);` in my wp-config.php ...

Should I be concerned???

Comment: just a warning, I doubt anything to worry about.  I would look into it though, if I were you.

Comment: Never ever try to hide errors. Fix them!